# Django model field for user-modifiable custom ordering

Tags: django

I have a Django app where values in a table can be reordered by the user, and new values can be added and old values can be deleted.

What is the "right" way to do this?

I could define `order = models.IntegerField()`

And then set that for each row to the right value in order to create the correct custom ordering as defined by the user.  BUT this has the major downside that every re-order will require every row after the change to be updated with a new `order`.  I could make the code a bit smarter and define the Integer chosen to be halfway between the previous and the next - but that still means that occasionally there will be a conflict and all rows will have to be updated.

One possible solution is to use a float.  Then the order of an inserted row can always be halfway between the previous and next... Are there any possible issues with using a float for ordering (particularly if the number of rows gets very high).

Is there a better/smarter/more built-in way to handle something like this?

Comment: You shouldn't try ordering a database.  Only what is shown to the user,  so either just order the querysets that make it or provide ways to store the users order preference

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear -- that's exactly what I want to do. (order the querysets / store the user preferences).  What I'm wondering is, what is the correct way to do that (when there can be lots and lots of adjustments/inserts/deletions/etc)

Comment: Your question is about storing the order which will always be flawed. You need to store the order preference, for example you can order answers on stack overflow by how active they are or how many votes they have

Comment: Let me explain:  I have a collection of "events" which can be ordered by the user in any custom order (not based on date, how many votes, etc).

I specifically want a way to create and save a custom ordering, and am trying to figure out the "right" way to do that

Comment: This might be the solution https://github.com/jpwatts/django-positions -- but is there a more "built in" way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm interested to hear any more clever solutions but I doubt there is anything simpler than integer order field, that's what I've been using.

To avoid value conflicts you need to not let the users customize this value directly, do it automatically behind the scenes based on some sort of ordering GUI (drag and drop, etc).

The workflow would be something like: show a list to the user, let them rearrange it however they want, submit the whole list back in order and update ordering for every record, starting with 1 and going +1.

If you are expecting users only to swap a pair of items occasionally, or insert new items into the middle, then you can update the order using UPDATE queries without looping through the list manually (`UPDATE table set orderid = orderid + 1 where orderid >= :position` to insert a new item at a certain position, etc).

You shouldn't have too many entries in that list to worry about DB update performance since users are expected to sort the items manually somehow, you can't give them a million records to sort. If it's the case then you probably need to do something extra so the number of items users are ordering is manageable.

Comment: thank you!  I did find github.com/jpwatts/django-positions which I may try out -- though it concerns me that there are some existing bugs in that package.  It may make sense to just go with what you suggested instead - though I do think there is a non-zero possibility that this app could expand to allow users to edit small parts of a larger list (and so there might actually be millions of entries).  Have you considered the float idea, or the "wide range of integers" idea?

Comment: This package might be even better than the django-positions one mentioned in my previous comment:  https://github.com/bfirsh/django-ordered-model

Comment: Floats and integers with some gaps (100, 200,...) are good if you modify the numbers yourself manually, it's convenient to just be able to change one number occasionally in db and forget about it. If you will be doing it automatically then you would need to add some extra checks, which might defeat the purpose of being a simpler option. I haven't used any of those libs, give them a try, sounds like they are still using integer ordering field with some convenience wrappers, which might be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for the discussion and thoughts!

Comment: For posterity - I ended up using github.com/bfirsh/django-ordered-model -- it's a nice package, and I'd recommend it.